# Preserve leading space in application yaml properties

Tags: yaml

I've got a list of properties in yml file

```
foo:
    bar:  One., Two., Three
```

when converting them to list

```
@Value("\${foo.bar}")
public var listOfBar: List<String> = mutableListOf()
```

Leading spaces are trimmed so I get
"One." "Two." "Three.", but what I need is " One." " Two." " Three." with spaces before each. Putting '\u0020' in front didn't helped, it got trimmed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this. And it's worked

```
 @Value("#{'\${foo.bar}'.split(',')}")
 public var listOfBar: List<String> = mutableListOf()
```

and surrounded properties with "

```
foo:
    bar:  " One., Two., Three"
```

Comment: Does this somehow resemble the "_just take the string and split it yourself_" approach? :)

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `"` around your values:

```yaml
foo:
    bar: " One."," Two."," Three"
```

Also you can use the explicit list format:

```yaml
foo:
    bar: 
        - " One."
        - " Two."
        - " Three"
```

Comment: I tried this. I got " expected <block end>, but found ',' "

Comment: @EgorGorko put the quotes around the whole value: `" One., Two., Three"`

Answer (score 1):

When you expect `List<String>` or `String[]`, Spring will split the input string value using `,` as separator.

To produce the string you want, you need to have the whitespace within quotes (otherwise it is ignored as per the yaml syntax):

```
foo:
    bar: " One., Two., Three"
```

However, the Spring default converter may call `trim()` on every token (I don't remember exactly if this is actually the case) simply dropping all your leadin/trailing spaces anyway.

In this case, you may want to register a different converter that doesn't trim or -- far better -- just take the string and split it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Removing spaces like this will break the purpose of trim() for yaml file.
Though I don't understand the use-case in which you may require this. but, I can suggest to use a custom pattern to achieve this as follows:

You can have tokens for spaces required in yaml file:

```
foo:
  bar:  $__$One., Two., Three$_$
```

Have a different class just to retrieve the configs:

```
public class Configs {
@Value("${foo.bar}")
private List<String> yourList;

public List<String> getYourList(){
 // before returning, replace $_$ with space in yourList
}
```

Use it in your code

```
class UseHere {

@Autowired
private Configs configs;

...

// read as follows
configs.getYourList().get(0);
...

}
```

Comment: Well, that's what it wanted to do, but lead is saying this is a crutch.